# How can I disable only an option in a list with angular 2?

Tags: angular

I have a list with radio buttons :

```
 <label *ngFor="let obj of RecipientType;let i = index"    class="radio-inline">
     <input formControlName="recipientType" type="radio" [value]="obj.id" name="recipientType" 
         (change)="onRecipientChange(obj.id,$event)">                       
 </label>
```

This list has 3 items .
How can I disable only the third option?
I tried to make like : `[disabled] = "obj.id==3"` but I can see that all radio buttons are disabled.I want onl the third one.

How can I do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you just wrap the `<input>` elements with a `<div *ngIf="i==2">`, and then do what you want to do for the special input.

Answer (score 3):

```
<label *ngFor="let obj of RecipientType;let i = index"    class="radio-inline">
    <input formControlName="recipientType" type="radio" [value]="obj.id" name="recipientType" 
     (change)="onRecipientChange(obj.id,$event)" [disabled]="i===2'>                       
</label>
```

Comment: Since ìndex starts at `0` it should be `[disabled]="i===2"`

Comment: unfortunately it does not work ? Can you make a plunkr ?

Comment: @AdrianBalasa This answer doesn't work with reactive forms, so don't worry about the plunker :)

Answer (score 0):

In reactive forms, the usually used `[disabled]="obj.id == 3"` or `[disabled]="i == 2"` doesn't work.

Since I do not know of a solution using reactive forms for this, to just disable ONE radio button in a group. The following does work, even though it sadly isn't related to reactive forms:

Let's use `document.getElementById` by assigning all radio buttons a unique id by using the the index. Then let's disable the one with index `2`.

So input field gets an `id` property added, using `{{i}}` which you declared as index value in your iteration:

```html
<input id="{{i}}" formControlName="recipientType" type="radio" [value]="obj.id" name="recipientType">
```

and e.g in the life-cycle hook `AfterViewInit` let's disable the input field with the index `2`:

```ts
ngAfterViewInit() {
  document.getElementById('2').disabled = true;
}
```

Here's a

### **[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/596gCPAsDOSe0NWssdAw?p=preview)**